# Cisco vpn connect failure

Tags: vpn, cisco

I am trying to connect through Cisco Anyconnect secure mobility client to my office vpn site but getting this error:

`The IPsec VPN connection was terminated due to an authentication failure or timeout. Please contact your network administrator.`

I already googled for this and tried out all suggested solutions like restart system or reinstall Cisco Client but nothing worked for me.

Also one weird thing that I observed is after clicking connect, it's not even asking for the pin code but it's giving above mentioned error straight away.

Any solution for this?

Comment: For what it's worth, I have this issue now. Using the same laptop, I can connect fine at home but not when I am at a satellite office. My colleagues in the satellite office do not have the same issue.